# createAppView cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm attempting to implement Google Analytics into my Android application however I'm following the example and it's giving me createAppView cannot be resolved or is not a field. I presume this is because it is not defined - but shouldn't it be defined in the example from google? I wouldn't expect them to make this kind of mistake and I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong on my end.

To see the example I'm using have a look under "complete example" here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Fields;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceManager;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Logger.LogLevel;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.MapBuilder;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.Tracker;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    private AnimationDrawable mGoButtonAnimation;
    Context c;
    boolean isAirPlaneMode;
    int simState;
    TelephonyManager tm;
    boolean NetworkConnection = false;
    AlertDialog mConfirmAlert = null;
    private static GoogleAnalytics mGa;
    private static Tracker mTracker;
    private static final String GA_LABEL = "Google Analytics";
    /*
     * Google Analytics configuration values.
     */
    // Placeholder property ID.
    private static final String GA_PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXX-Y";

    // Dispatch period in seconds.
    private static final int GA_DISPATCH_PERIOD = 30;

    // Prevent hits from being sent to reports, i.e. during testing.
    private static final boolean GA_IS_DRY_RUN = false;

    // GA Logger verbosity.
    private static final LogLevel GA_LOG_VERBOSITY = LogLevel.INFO;

    // Key used to store a user's tracking preferences in SharedPreferences.
    private static final String TRACKING_PREF_KEY = "trackingPreference";

    /*
     * Method to handle basic Google Analytics initialization. This call will
     * not block as all Google Analytics work occurs off the main thread.
     */
    private void initializeGa() {
        mGa = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        mTracker = mGa.getTracker(GA_PROPERTY_ID);

        // Set dispatch period.
        GAServiceManager.getInstance().setLocalDispatchPeriod(
                GA_DISPATCH_PERIOD);

        // Set dryRun flag.
        mGa.setDryRun(GA_IS_DRY_RUN);

        // Set Logger verbosity.
        mGa.getLogger().setLogLevel(GA_LOG_VERBOSITY);

        // Set the opt out flag when user updates a tracking preference.
        SharedPreferences userPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        userPrefs
        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                if (key.equals(TRACKING_PREF_KEY)) {
                    GoogleAnalytics
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                    .setAppOptOut(
                            sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,
                                    false));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        initializeGa();
        StartActivity.getGaTracker().set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, GA_LABEL);
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        simState = tm.getSimState();
        System.out.println("Sim State" + simState);
        Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_button);
        // Set GO button to drawable animation
        goButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.go_button_animation);
        mGoButtonAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) goButton.getBackground();

        // check network availability
        NetworkConnection = CheckNetworkAvailability
                .CheckNetworkAvailability(StartActivity.this);
        if (!NetworkConnection) {

            showAlert("Network Connection is not Available");
        }
        isAirPlaneMode = isAirplaneModeOn(StartActivity.this);
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start UpdateActivity

                if (simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) {
                    showAlert("Sim Card is absent, Please insert a Net10 Sim Card");

                } else if (isAirPlaneMode != false) {
                    showAlert("Please Insert a Net10 Sim Card or Turn on the AirPlane Mode and Re-Run the app");

                } else if (simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED
                        || simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED
                        || simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED
                        || simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN) {
                    showAlert("Sim Card is absent, Please insert a Net10 Sim Card");
                } else if (simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(StartActivity.this,
                            UpdateActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Send a screen view when the Activity is displayed to the user.
        StartActivity.getGaTracker().send(MapBuilder.createAppView.build());
    }

    /*
     * Returns the Google Analytics tracker.
     */
    public static Tracker getGaTracker() {
        return mTracker;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the Google Analytics instance.
     */
    public static GoogleAnalytics getGaInstance() {
        return mGa;
    }

    /**
     * * Gets the state of Airplane Mode. * * @param context * @return true if
     * enabled.
     */
    public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        // Animate GO button when corresponding window is in focus
        mGoButtonAnimation.start();
    }

    private void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                StartActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        mConfirmAlert = builder.create();
        mConfirmAlert.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a typo within the [example provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/advanced). Actually, createAppView is a method and not variable, then:

```
StartActivity.getGaTracker().send(MapBuilder.createAppView.build());
```

should be:

```
StartActivity.getGaTracker().send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
```

Comment: the problem is that MapBuilder doesn't even exist in the first place ! `MapBuilder cannot be resolved` even though I have used `import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.*;` it seems that Google's documentation is out of date with their v3 analytics library.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `MapBuilder.createAppView`, it should be `HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()` in Google Analytics API v4

replace

`StartActivity.getGaTracker().send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());`

to

`StartActivity.getGaTracker().send(HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());`